# Конструктор html для Golang

Tags: html, golang

Использует ли кто ни будь "визуальный" конструктор html (накидать элементов перетаскивая) для golang, встречал ли кто ни будь "визуальный" конструктор шаблона html для golang?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Что вообще должно означать "html конструктор для golang"?

Comment: Визуально накидать элементов (надписи, поля ввода), чтоб не создавать весь код html руками

Comment: TinyMCE и прочие WYSIWYG-редакторы уже изобретены.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю о каком-либо встроенном "визуальном" конструкторе HTML для Golang, но существуют некоторые библиотеки и фреймворки, которые могут помочь в создании HTML-шаблонов для Golang, такие как:

- html/template
- text/template
- mustache
- Go template

Вы можете использовать их для создания и отображения шаблонов HTML, но они не предоставляют "визуального" конструктора HTML.

Если вы хотите создавать элементы HTML путем перетаскивания и вставки из UI,  вот некоторые из визуальных редакторов:

- Adobe Dreamweaver
- BlueGriffon
- Aptana Studio
- CKEditor
- TinyMCE